# SvelteKit: Is there a way to create multiple GET endpoints in a single +server.js file?

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

This is an example of what i'm trying to achieve... I'm wondering if there is something like this in sveltekit without creating a separate file to handle the "GET_2" endpoint.

```
// +server.ts
export const GET: RequestHandler = async () => {
  // ...stuff
};


export const GET_2: RequestHandler = async () => {
  // ...stuff
};
```

Comment: This question doesn't really make any sense. Ask yourself, how would you choose which handler to run upon receiving a GET request to that endpoint?

Comment: @ThomasHennes: The format shown in the question wouldn't quite work, but its a sensible question. You can also have multiple POST endpoints in a file already by defining various form actions.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge that is not possible, [the `+server` documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server) merely states that for each HTTP method of `GET`, `POST`, `PATCH`, `PUT` and `DELETE` a handler can be exported.

You could work around that by using query parameters and then delegating to corresponding functions in the file.